# jQuery Tab auto resize width to content width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of tabs, and they use ajax to load their content.
One of the ajax content, is overflowing, instead of having the tabs nicely re-size to accommodate the increase in content width.

Can I do this via an option, or do I have to track the change and do it via events?

I've tried:

```
$( '#tabs' ).tabs({ 
        disabled: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        effect: 'ajax',
        autoHeight: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        contentAnimTime: 600,
        contentEasing: 'easeInOutExpo',
        tabsAnimTime: 300
    });
```

But to no avail.

The only other solution I can think, is capture tab title clicks, and then pro grammatically resize the tab to fit the content.